# OID addressing with net-snmp

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I am extending my snmp agent with a self developed MIB file.
What I've noticed is that when I do a walk it prints my variables as

```
MY-MIB::myvariable.0
```

But I've specifically placed the variable at at an OID which is does not end at 0.

I am using the net-snmp library functions:

```
netsnmp_create_handler_registration
```

and also

```
netsnmp_register_read_only_ulong_instance
```

to register my instances.

It only seems to happen with `netsnmp_create_handler_registration`. But when I specify `reg_oid_len` one shorter, it double registers some of the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going in to this assuming that your question is 'Why is a 0 appended to my OID?'
In order to access any *scalar* value you have to append a .0 to the leaf node of the tree. If you were attempting to address a table entry you would need to append the index of the entry into the table.  Not using the .0 on a scalar will typically cause problems if you're not using the OID as the argument to something like a bulkget or a walk, i.e.

```
$ snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.1.120 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
  SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: things, stuff

$ snmpget -v2c -c public 192.168.1.120 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1  
  SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID

$ snmpwalk -v2c -c public 192.168.1.120 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1
  SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: things, stuff
```

see [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/mailman/message/16580196/) net-snmp mailing list entry for more explicit detail on why scalars end in 0.